# Simplex Method: What pivot element, as none fullfill criteria?

Tags: linear-programming

I transformed the linear programming problem, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ also has to be non-negative:
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrl} 
(P) & \text{min. } & \xi  & = & x_1  & + & 3x_2 &\\
 & \text{st. } & -x_1  &   &      &\geq & -2.5\\
 &              &       &   & x_2  &\geq & 1.5\\
 &      & x_1 & + & 2x_2 &\geq & 5 \\
\end{array}
$$
to standard form:
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrl} 
(P) & \text{-max. } & -\xi  & = & -x_1  & - & 3x_2 &\\
 & \text{st. } & x_1  &   &      &\leq & 2.5\\
 &              &       & - & x_2  &\leq & -1.5\\
 &      & -x_1 & - & 2x_2 &\leq & -5 \\
\end{array}
$$

I know this problem easily can be solved with dual simplex, however, would like to solve it with primal simplex, if it is possible. I can add the parameter $\mu=5+\epsilon$, when making the simplex table, so the primal simplex becomes feasible:
\begin{array}{r|rrrrr|r}
               & x_1 & x_2 & w_1 & w_2 & w_3 &    \\ \hline
               &  -1 + \mu &  -3 + \mu &   0 &   0 &   0 &  0 \\ \hline
           w_1 &  1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  2.5 + \mu \\
           w_2 &   0 &  -1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  -1.5 + \mu \\
           w_3 &   -1 &   -2 &   0 &   0 &   1 & -5 + \mu 
\end{array}

However, my minimum ratio test becomes:
$$
\text{min}\left\{\frac{7.5+\epsilon}{0},-3.5-\epsilon,\frac{-\epsilon}{2}\right\}
$$
It should then be the one, that are minimum of these, however the minimum shall be positive, and not zero, however, none of these fulfill this, when having chosen the second column, $x_2$, as my pivot column as $-3+\mu<-1+\mu$.

Any help on what to do? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong unfortunately.

Comment: You may see the [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189) for inserting simplex tableaux. \begin{array}{rrrrrr|r}
               & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &    \\ \hline
           s_1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  8 \\
           s_2 &   1 &  -1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  4 \\
           s_3 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & 12 \\ \hline
               &  -1 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  0
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, that I am able to make the simplex table - I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I think you may try ([tag:two-phase-simplex]) method.